# Don't display status bar for navigation tabs in react-bootstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

In react-bootstrap the [tabs](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#tabs) are rendered as `a` tags with `href='#'`. This means that on hover and after clicking a tab, there will be `<site-url>#` in the browser's status bar. This doesn't really mean anything to the user so I'd like to not show that. I've tried using `preventDefault()` and `removeAttribute('href')` in the `onSelect` handler but it doesn't seem to work. Is there any decent way to do this while still using react-bootstrap?